# Проверить подписан на канал YouTube

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение и в приложении есть игровые монеты, теперь, я хочу сделать, чтоб по кнопке предлагалось подписаться на канал в Yotube и за подписку начеслялись монеты , как все это можно проверить?